# Why Is the raycast detecting the player, despite how it's being created far infront of it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In this 2D game I'm making, the player has a gun which, when shot at a target, pushes the player backwards. The recoil is your only method of movement.

In the code below, I find the normalized vector for the angle of the player, which the recoil force acts along. I create a ray, as the gun only produces the recoil knockback if a target is hit. The ray uses the same vector as a direction, and also as a unit for how far away to start. I originally started the raycast at only a few units in front of the player, but have increased it to exaggerate the problem. The ray continues for another 100 units, or until it collides with an object.

[image: Code of raycast being created]

However, the raycast still collides with the player, but ONLY when facing directly right. The two logs below are as follows: the object collided with; the normalized vector that the ray travels along.

[image: Logs of player direction and collided object]

While I could put the player on another layer, I am interested to know what might be the root of this problem. It's almost as if the ray starts far to the right but travels back to the left. It just seems too obsure to figure out for myself, so if anyone could help, that'd be great :D

I'm also wondering if there's a smarter way to find the normalized vector of recoil. Any improvements are welcome :)

Comment: When you paste code, paste text, not a picture.

Comment: Try [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html) to visualize what happens when you are facing directly right, and update your post if this adds useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you make an empty `gameobject` child of your player and put it just at the tip of your gun then use it as the starting point for your `raycast`.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I was using `transform.TransformPoint` which, when I used the player's normalized direction vector, would be based on the player's direction, instead of world direction. When looking up at 90 degrees, the normalized direction vector is (0,1), but this 1 on the y axis is based off of the player's y axis, so the ray starts 1 unit to the left of the player as it's up from the player's perspective. Couldn't have figured this without `Debug.DrawRay` :D